# How to fix error in Optima Express IDX Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i am having this error "**Sorry we are experiencing system issues. Please try again.**" when install "**Optima Express IDX Plugin**" plugin. and also website load slowly. Errors will placed in the property listing page.
what's the reason for that issue?
anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you register the Optima Express plugin, the URL of your site is recorded and used for the IDX content and permalinks.

If the the message “Sorry, We are experiencing system issues” appears within the IDX content on some pages, it is likely that one of the following occurred:

```
URL Change
Disabling and Re-enabling the Optima Express plugin
```

To resolve this, you will need to refresh the registration of the Optima Express plugin by going to

Dashboard > Optima Express > Register > Refresh Registration (Click the link)